# Printing digits goes wrong in R

Tags: r

I'm very confused. In R I type

```
print(pi,20)
```

and I get this output

```
3.141592653589793116
```

The last 3 digts `116` should be `238`. How can that be?

Also, is it possible to get more digits of pi in R  ?

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point Computers store values with a finite number of bits and have limited precision.

Comment: There are packages that enable using arbitrarily precise numbers, but of course you'd need then to somehow get or calculate a value of pi with the desired precision.

Comment: you can use the `Rmpfr` package and `Const("pi", prec = 260)` to have corrects digits for pi

Comment: `pi` is a predefined constant, it's not calculated at runtime. You are seeing the limitations of `print`, not inaccuracies in the constant. Try `sprintf("%.100f",pi)`

Comment: @Roland, the reason to close is *wrong*. This isn't about *floating point numbers*, it's about the way R calculates `pi`. In fact, @etienne already provided a *correct answer*. A *different* package contains a better constant value

Comment: [Checking the source](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RRO/blob/master/R-src/src/library/base/R/constants.R) it looks like `pi` *is* calculated in a coarse way as `4*atan(1)`. This has nothing to do with floating point calculations. The actual culprit is how `atan` is calculated in R. Etienne's comment should be the correct answer

Comment: I'ts very strange that R uses 4*atan(1) instead of raw digits of the true pi.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos atan(1)  is exactly pi/4. That it isn't in R is a consequence of floating point imprecision and the approximations necessary to calculate it on a computer. And of course, the Rmpfr package implements arbitrary precise numbers.

Comment: Anyway, I've reopened it. Feel free to submit an answer.

Comment: I just read the comments. Maybe I'm missing something, but is someone here implying that a computer could store pi _exactly_?